# lvalue required as left operand of the assignment

Tags: c

`(num%2==0)? sum1+=num:sum2+=num;`

why does this code give a lvalue required as left operand of the assignment error?

I tried reading about the error but from what i understood this happens when assigning a value in an incorrect manner. Like 8+a=b which is not my case.
In my case i am doing sum1 = sum1+num;

anyone know why perhaps?

Comment: This looks like an attempt to abuse the ternary conditional operator for something it is not intended to do. Why are you writing your code like this instead of using simple `if` and `else`?

Comment: Unfortunately this is rather a question i have been given and must write out the result of the program. I am aware of the fact that there is zero purpose to write code like this

Comment: @dudex198 `?:` has rather limited uses. There are some rare cases where it does give more readable code than if-else. But the main purpose of it is writing function-like macros. The down sides are: less readable and comes with a few subtle type rules, plus implicit promotion.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Operator precedence. `?:` has higher precedence than `+=` so this gets treated as:

```
((num%2==0) ? sum1+=num : sum2) += num;
```

Which is of course nonsense. Quick fix:

```
(num%2==0) ? (sum1+=num) : (sum2+=num);
```

However, there's no apparent need to use `?:` here so you should probably go with `if`-`else` for better readability.

Comment: @dudex198 Btw this will only work if `sum1` and `sum2` are compatible types.

Comment: From [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence): *The expression in the middle of the conditional operator (between ? and :) is parsed as if parenthesized: its precedence relative to ?: is ignored.* So, only the last expression needs to be parenthesized - this works, too: `num % 2 == 0 ? sum1 += num : (sum2 += num);`

Comment: @AdrianMole Mmhm, so be aware of `printf("%d\n", (1 ? 1,1 : 2,2) );` which will compile and print 2  :)

Comment: Hehe - nice one! Also interesting (but off-topic) is that OP's code is OK in C++, where ?: and += have the same precedence.